# Asp menu not displaying properly

Tags: asp.net

I have this website created in asp.net. On my test server, it works properly in every browser, but on the client's server it doesn't work in Chrome.

Apart from the `web.config` file, the files are an exact copy of each other, which makes me think that it is a configuration problem (either a problem with web.config or with the IIS/site configuration)

Right now, it should look like this when hovering over a menu item:

[image]

but when hovering the item, the submenu doesn't appear, and instead yo can click on the item to see this:

[image]

I kinda see all submenu items, but clearly not properly (I can barely read them).

Comment: check that all the css and js files are in the project

Comment: As I said on my post, all my files are exactly the same on both servers, I don't think that that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could be missing CSS files - have a look at the developer tools in Chrome (F12) and see if any resources are failing to load.

Comment: As I said on my post, all my files are exactly the same on both servers, I don't think that that's the problem.

Comment: The files may be on disk but that doesn't mean they are being served/loaded. Dev tools will highlight a problem there. You could also try diffing the served page from each environment and see if the html is being created differently.

Comment: When opening devtools no error / warning is shown, and every file needed from the project is loaded. When I compare both devtools the same files from my project are shown. The thing I've noticed now, is that on my clients server, there are two less ScriptResource.axd files loading

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by adding an App_Browsers folder in my project, then a file inside called safari.browser

Inside of it I added the following code:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="safari1plus">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu" adapterType="" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

And that was it.